# knowrob visualisation_canvas

Tags: knowrob

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to get the visualisation_canvas to run, as described in the knowrob basics tutorial. However, I keep getting this error message:

[1]  ?- visualisation_canvas(C).
ERROR: Unhandled exception: jpl:jFindClass/2: Undefined procedure: jpl:jni_func/3

Tried it on cturtle and diamondback (on 2 different machines), same result.

Any hint would be much appreciated. Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9674/knowrob-visualisation_canvas/) by [Mate Wolfram](https://answers.ros.org/users/402/mate-wolfram/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2011-04-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem's resolved. A former installation of SWI-Prolog seems to have caused the trouble. Uninstalling SWI-Prolog and reinstalling knowrob's dependencies helped in my case.

---

Originally posted by [Mate Wolfram](https://answers.ros.org/users/402/mate-wolfram/) with karma: 76 on 2011-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

this is strange - it usually works :) Which operating system and which java version do you use? (java -version)

Have you tried the following:

- roscd jpl && make clean && make
- rosmake knowrob
- rosrun rosprolog rosprolog ias_knowledge_base

  ?- jpl_is_true(@(true)).

  true.

If any of the outputs sounds like an error, please copy/paste the error messages.

HTH,Moritz

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2011-04-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) on 2011-04-11**:
another idea: for ubuntu and diamondback, you can also use the debian packages: sudo apt-get install ros-diamondback-knowrob

**Comment by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) on 2011-04-10**:
Hmm... just the runtime environment is not enough, you'll need the full JDK. Either OpenJDK or Sun Java 6 work fine, and normally, you should not even need to set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Sounds strange -- all dependencies are installed? (rosdep satisfy knowrob)

**Comment by [Mate Wolfram](https://answers.ros.org/users/402/mate-wolfram/) on 2011-04-10**:
the two machines I tried this on, are running a 32bit ubuntu lucid and a 64bit ubuntu maverick

**Comment by [Mate Wolfram](https://answers.ros.org/users/402/mate-wolfram/) on 2011-04-10**:
I fixed the first two errors by setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH accordingly, however the third error and the warning still persist (and the visualisation_canvas still won't work ;-) )

**Comment by [Mate Wolfram](https://answers.ros.org/users/402/mate-wolfram/) on 2011-04-10**:
Then I get:

```
?- jpl_is_true(@(true)).
true.
```

**Comment by [Mate Wolfram](https://answers.ros.org/users/402/mate-wolfram/) on 2011-04-10**:
Warning: /home/mate/robotics/ros-external/knowrob/semweb/prolog/init.pl:23:
Goal (directive) failed: user:jpl_set_default_jvm_opts([-Xmx256M])

**Comment by [Mate Wolfram](https://answers.ros.org/users/402/mate-wolfram/) on 2011-04-10**:
ERROR: /home/mate/robotics/ros-external/knowrob/semweb/prolog/init.pl:23:
jpl:jpl_set_default_jvm_opts/1: Undefined procedure: jpl:jni_set_default_jvm_opts/2

**Comment by [Mate Wolfram](https://answers.ros.org/users/402/mate-wolfram/) on 2011-04-10**:
ERROR:/home/mate/robotics/ros-external/knowrob/semweb/prolog/init.pl:22:
/home/mate/robotics/ros-external/knowrob/3rdparty/jpl/prolog/jpl.pl:4643: Initialization goal raised exception:           library `java' does not exist (Please add directory holding libjava.so to $LD_LIBRARY_PATH)

**Comment by [Mate Wolfram](https://answers.ros.org/users/402/mate-wolfram/) on 2011-04-10**:
ERROR: /home/mate/robotics/ros-external/knowrob/semweb/prolog/init.pl:22:
'$open_shared_object'/3: libjava.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

**Comment by [Mate Wolfram](https://answers.ros.org/users/402/mate-wolfram/) on 2011-04-10**:
on 'rosrun rosprolog rosprolog ias_knowledge_base' I get the following errors:

**Comment by [Mate Wolfram](https://answers.ros.org/users/402/mate-wolfram/) on 2011-04-10**:
the machine I can currently access is running
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.9.7) (6b20-1.9.7-0ubuntu1~10.04.1)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 19.0-b09, mixed mode)

AFAIK, the other one's got Sun JDK

making jpl works fine, just a couple of warnings, no errors.
rosmake knowrob works fine as well